# For every Non Deterministic polynomial Turing Machine $M$ exists $L(\overline{M})\in P \Leftrightarrow P=NP$

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is straightforward.
On the other hand for $\Rightarrow$ direction I have an idea of the prove but I don't sure about it.
For NTM, Non Deterministic Turing Machine, $M$, for example TN that decide $SAT$, $L(M)=L(\overline{\overline{M}})\in NP$. It's clear that exists NTM $M'=\overline{M}$ such that $L(\overline{M})\in NP\Rightarrow L(\overline{\overline{M}})\in P$ so $P=NP$.
Is this the proof correct?

$\overline M$ is a TM that accept and reject final states swaped

Comment: Please, write a reason for the downvote, otherwise I can't understand

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but the question si unclear to me. 1) what does "take place" mean in this context? 2) What is $N$? 3) Whats "a frame of the prove"? 4) Whats an "official enough" proof?  5) Why does $L(\overline{M})\in NP$ imply $L(M) = L(\overline{\overline{M}}) \in P$?.

Comment: Thanks man! I fixed some of the points

Comment: I think your $M'$ would be with $L(M')\in co-NP$ instead of $NP$

Comment: Can you confirm that this a correct interpretation of the clam you want to show?
For every non-deterministic polynomial-time Turing machine $M$ the following is true: $L(\overline{M}) \in P$ if and only if $P=NP$.

Comment: Yes @Steven, it's what I meant

Comment: Sorry @Steven if I confused you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming the OP meant the question is $(\forall M. M \text{ is nondeterministic polynomial TM }, L(\overline{M})\in P) \iff P=NP$.
Look at Steven's answer for the solution regarding the other interpretation of this question.

---

This proof assumes $\overline M$ is a TM that accepts $(w, x)$ where $w$ is a witness for $x $, iff $M$ rejected $(w,x)$. This **does not** imply that $L(\overline {M})=\overline{L(M)}$. Thanks for Nathanuek for correcting me in this one.

In this case, the OP's solution looks correct to me. I will write it here again, a bit more organized.

Lets assume the left side of the question, and we will prove P=NP.

Let $M$ a non-deterministic polynomial turing machine for $SAT$. Then, we can define $M'=\overline M$. From our assumption, we know that $L(\overline{M'})\in P$. But notice that $M=\overline{\overline{M}}=\overline{M'}$, and therefore $SAT=L(M)=L(\overline{M'})\in P$. Since $SAT\in NP-complete$, and we showed that $SAT\in P$ then $P=NP$.

---

This is an "old" proof assuming $\overline{M}$ is a TM for the complement language of $M$.

Lets assume the left side of the question, and we will prove $P=NP$.

Let $M$ be a non-deterministic polynomial turing machine for $SAT$. Then, by assumption we know that $L(\overline M)\in P$ and thus $\overline{SAT} = \overline{L(M)}\in P$.

Therefore there is some **deterministic** polynomial TM $M'$ that solves $\overline{SAT}$. We know that $P$ is closed under negation and thus $co-P=P$ (we usually dont even write $co-P$ since this always holds). In other words, we know that there is $\overline{M'}$ which is also **deterministic and polynomial**. Therefore $SAT = L(\overline{M'})\in co-P=P$

Since $SAT\in NP-complete$ then $P=NP$

Comment: I think you wrongly assume that $L(\overline{M}) = \overline{L(M)}$. For example, if for an entry $u$ there exist both an accepting path and a rejecting path, then $u\in L(M)$ AND $u\in L(\overline{M})$.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I will fix the answer in a few minutes